# Pushing image to Github packages throws "denied: not_found: owner not found"

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-packages

I have the following github workflow:

```
name: TS Service Build

permissions:
  packages: write

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 18.x

      - name: Docker Login
        run: |
          export CR_PAT=${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
          echo $CR_PAT | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Build & Push
        run: |
          docker build -t ghcr.io/vli20/${{ inputs.name }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }} . --build-arg path=${{ inputs.path }} --build-arg module=${{ inputs.module }}
          docker push ghcr.io/vli20/${{ inputs.name }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }}
```

I Have created a token with the following permissions:
[image]

And assigned it to a secret with the same name. `${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}`

It seems like the login is successful:
[image]

But when I am trying to push the image to github packages, I am getting the following error:
`denied: not_found: owner not found`

I am using a private repo (free tier).

I only could find this webpage, but it doesn't seems to be helpful:
https://issuehint.com/issue/goreleaser/goreleaser/2815

What did I miss?

Comment: Typos in `docker build` and `docker push` commands i.e. repo owner's name is `vli20` but your username is [`vlio20`](https://github.com/vlio20). You need to fix that. Better yet, use [`github.repository_owner`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: @Azeem, please post this as an answer and I will happily accept it as it resolved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> denied: not_found: owner not found

There are typos in `docker build` and `docker push` commands i.e. repo owner's name is `vli20` but your username is [`vlio20`](https://github.com/vlio20). You need to fix that.

Better yet, use [`github.repository_owner`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) instead of hardcoding it.

For more details, see [Publishing and installing a package with GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions).